# Equation from google doc in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I didn't known where to ask this king of question and I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129110/which-stack-exchange-is-proper-for-asking-microsoft-word-related-questions) so ... :

I have a file done in `google doc`, It can be export in `.docx`. Doing this, all equations are replace by white squares...

The only clue I have found to solve this problem was to change font in `MSword`, but it didn't solve anything for me...

Any suggestion welcome ! Thanks

Comment: Can you save them as image files from the Google doc? If you can, then re-insert the image files into the Word document.

Comment: @RichMichaels, thanks for the idea, but I would like to be able to edit it in word aswell.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to open the word, select the characters of the equation and select any font. It seems to be a problems with fonts. Hope this could solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).